# Change dependent drop down column in Google Script Editor

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

**How can I change this script to apply drop downs in Column B & C instead of A & B? (The script seems to work perfectly if the drop downs are in Column A & B.)**

Column A will be for dates, column B will be drop down list (from "Crops" sheet) and column C will be a dependent drop down list (from "Crops" sheet). When I change the "First Level Column" (line 3) and "Second Level Column" (line 4) to equal 2 (col B) & 3 (col C) respectively in the script editor and then input a date in column A in the worksheet, the drop down options in Column B & C disappear completely.

```
var MainWsName = "Harvest";
var CropsWsName = "Crops";
var firstLevelColumn = 2;
var secondLevelColumn = 3;


var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(MainWsName);
var wsCrops = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CropsWsName);
var Crops = wsCrops.getRange(2, 1,wsCrops.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();

function onEdit(activeCell){
  var activeCell = ws.getActiveCell();
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName == MainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 1){ 
     applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r)
  }//close If
 }// end onEdit

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){
 if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      } else {
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var filteredCrops = Crops.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredCrops.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
      }
} 
  
function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the onEdit(e) was working for column B at all

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (sh.getName() == 'Harvest' && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart < 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    applyFirstLevelValidation(e.value, e.range.rowStart)
  }
}
```

You can't use parameters with trigger functions. I don't see how the onEdit(e)

Comment: Hi Cooper, I deleted everything included in the original onEdit function and replaced it with your suggested edit above. While the drop down list works in Column B, the dependent drop down in Col C does not appear. Any ideas? I'm fairly new at using code, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: Does `applyFirstLevelValidation` work by itself?

Comment: I've tried the applyFirstLevelValidation on its own, but I'm not certain I tested it properly. I couldn't get it to work (which is perhaps where the issue lies). Here's a link to the worksheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IKCxAv1NxUR1wgcmXitOZuQXUCnGgLawvruZZZc61zE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can write another function just to call it with the appropriate parameters and single step through it with the debugger to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: I'll look into it. I put this function together using a few tutorials, so my knowledge is  pretty limited, hence the reason why I couldn't get it to work when I adjusted the parameters.